# GRUB2 won't install into MBR from chroot

Tags: grub2, boot-loader, mbr

I got a blank screen after the "Welcome to GRUB" greetings.

I ran `grub-install` and `grub-mkconfig` from a chroot, but still couldn't get to the GRUB menu.

Because of the setup (former dual boot with another GNU/Linux distribution) I thought maybe it was using GRUB-legacy, so I ran both [this first method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180026/26952), which confirmed that GRUB-legacy was not installed, and [this second method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180027/26952), which confirmed GRUB2 was installed.  However, confusingly [this third method](https://serverfault.com/a/61412/143834) seemed to provide evidence that GRUB-legacy was installed.

Consequently, I decided to wipe the MBR and reinstall a fresh GRUB2 on it.  As suggested [elsewhere](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-can-i-wipe-the-mbr-clean-and-remove-grub-430827/), I used `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/hda bs=1 count=446` to wipe the MBR (above commands and a reboot all confirmed the success of this command).

Finally, I chrooted again into my working partition and ran `grub-install`, which reported "Installation finished" without errors **but didn't seem to actually modify the MBR**.

Now I'm lost, how am I supposed to install GRUB2 on the MBR ?

FWIW, `/boot` is on `/dev/sda3`, which is set as "bootable".

For now I ended up installing LILO (I'm running Slackware) but I'm still willing to fix this issue.

### Update :

I couldn't help but run `grub-install` again after booting through LILO.  This time the MBR was successfully modified according to the second method mentioned above (though the third method still showed LILO but I guess it's only a remaining useless string) and the fact that I got the GRUB greetings.

**I suppose I'm missing some binding besides `/sys` and `/proc` when running `grub-install` through chroot** (yes I tried again)**, but which one(s) ?  It says "No error reported"…**

(Still get the blank screen, though…  Gonna stick to LILO for now.)

Comment: The “Welcome to GRUB” message indicates to me that it’s installed in MBR. However, it doesn’t sound like partitions with OS’s were detected. Do your grub configuration files contain anything related to your OS partitions?

Comment: @Peschke The greetings only appears when I run `grub-install` from the complete installation.  It does not appear when I run it from the chroot.  I'll edit the title to make it clear.

Comment: I think you should add to your question: the list of your drives (hda? sda?), which one your system boots from, the list of partitions on them and the actual `grub-install` and `grub-mkconfig` you ran, with all the arguments.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou I’m not clear on what you mean then. What happens after you run a `grub-install` and reboot?

Comment: Nevermind, I don't have time to dig this issue currently so I'll stick to LILO.  @somethingSomething Thanks, it seems that the second link has a number of different options which I may give a try.

Comment: This list of directories to use with the chroot scenario ("for dir in proc dev sys etc bin sbin var usr lib lib64 tmp; ..." comes from Nathan Kidd's answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/254491/failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow/531051#531051